NIntegrate is incorrect
NIntegrate[3*Exp[x^5], {y, 0, 64}, {x, y^(1/3), 4}] gives 3.912376599715969*10^443 but WolframAlpha gives a different answer: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int+3e%5E%28x%5E5%29+dx+dy%2C+x%3Dy%5E%281%2F3%29..4%3By%3D0..64
The answer is 7.8*10^443.

Wolfram Alpha doesn't do numerical integration. It does the exact integration, then numericize the answer: N@Integrate[3*Exp[x^5], {y, 0, 64}, {x, y^(1/3), 4}]. There is no need for numerical integration. And if you really want it, you have to change the options to get better accuracy (e.g. increase WorkingPrecision or change Method ...).

Look at Options[NIntegrate, WorkingPrecision]. MachinePrecision does not track nor control precision; it is fast but must be used with caution.
